# Jest test Animated.View for React-Native app

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, react-native, jestjs

I try to test an `Animated.View` with Jest for React-Native. When I set a property `visible` to true, it supposed to animate my view from `opacity 0` to `opacity 1`.

This is what my component renders:

```
<Animated.View
    style={{
        opacity: opacityValue,
    }}
>
    <Text>{message}</Text>
</Animated.View>
```

Where `opacityValue` gets updated when the props `visible` changes:

```
Animated.timing(
    this.opacityValue, {
        toValue: this.props.visible ? 1 : 0,
        duration: 350,
    },
).start(),
```

I want to make sure my view is visible when I set it the property `visible=true`. Although it takes some time for the view to become visible and as the test runs, the opacity is equal to `0`.

This is my test it:

```
it('Becomes visible when visible=true', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(
        <MessageBar
            visible={true}
        />
    ).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

I was wondering how I could have Jest to wait? Or how I could test this to make sure the view becomes visible when I set the props to true?

Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating an Animated stub for tests.

I see you are using visible as a property, so an working example is:

Components code

```
import React from 'react';                                                                                                                                                                            
import { Animated, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';                                                                                                                                

// This class will control the visible prop                                                                                                                                                                                                  
class AnimatedOpacityController extends React.Component {                                                                                                                                             

  constructor(props, ctx) {                                                                                                                                                                           
    super(props, ctx);                                                                                                                                                                                
    this.state = {                                                                                                                                                                                    
      showChild: false,                                                                                                                                                                               
    };                                                                                                                                                                                                
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                   

  render() {                                                                                                                                                                                          
    const { showChild } = this.state;                                                                                                                                                                 
    return (                                                                                                                                                                                          
      <View>                                                                                                                                                                                          
        <AnimatedOpacity visible={this.state.showChild} />                                                                                                                                            
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ showChild: !showChild })}>                                                                                                                   
          <Text>{showChild ? 'Hide' : 'Show' } greeting</Text>                                                                                                                                        
        </TouchableOpacity>                                                                                                                                                                           
      </View>                                                                                                                                                                                         
    );                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                   

}                                                                                                                                                                                                     

// This is your animated Component                                                                                                                                                                                                   
class AnimatedOpacity extends React.Component {                                                                                                                                                       

  constructor(props, ctx) {                                                                                                                                                                           
    super(props, ctx);                                                                                                                                                                                
    this.state = {                                                                                                                                                                                    
      opacityValue: new Animated.Value(props.visible ? 1 : 0),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    };                                                                                                                                                                                                
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {                                                                                                                                                              
    if (nextProps.visible !== this.props.visible) {                                                                                                                                                   
      this._animate(nextProps.visible);                                                                                                                                                               
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                   

  _animate(visible) {                                                                                                                                                                                 
    Animated.timing(this.state.opacityValue, {                                                                                                                                                        
      toValue: visible ? 1 : 0,                                                                                                                                                                       
      duration: 350,                                                                                                                                                                                  
    }).start();                                                                                                                                                       
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                   

  render() {                      
    return (                                                                                                                                                                                          
      <Animated.View style={{ opacity: this.state.opacityValue }}>                                                                                                                                    
        <Text>Hello World</Text>                                                                                                                                                                      
      </Animated.View>                                                                                                                                                                                
    );                                                                                                                                                                                                 

  }                                                                                                                                                                                                   

}                                                                                                                                                                                                     


export { AnimatedOpacityController, AnimatedOpacity };
```

Now moving to tests

```
import React from 'react';                                                                                                                                                                            
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';                                                                                                                                                           
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

import { AnimatedOpacityController, AnimatedOpacity } from '../AnimatedOpacity';                                                                                                                    


jest.mock('Animated', () => {                                                                                                                                                                         
  const ActualAnimated = require.requireActual('Animated');                                                                                                                                           
  return {                                                                                                                                                                                            
    ...ActualAnimated,                                                                                                                                                                                
    timing: (value, config) => {                                                                                                                                                                      
      return {                                                                                                                                                                                        
        start: (callback) => {
          value.setValue(config.toValue);
          callback && callback()
        },                                                                                                                                                  
      };                                                                                                                                                                                              
    },                                                                                                                                                                                                
  };                                                                                                                                                                                                  
});                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

it('renders visible', () => {                                                                                                                                                                         
  expect(                                                                                                                                                                                             
    renderer.create(                                                                                                                                                                                  
      <AnimatedOpacity visible={true} />                                                                                                                                                              
    ).toJSON()                                                                                                                                                                                        
  ).toMatchSnapshot();                                                                                                                                                                                
});                                                                                                                                                                                                   

it('renders invisible', () => {                                                                                                                                                                       
  expect(                                                                                                                                                                                             
    renderer.create(                                                                                                                                                                                  
      <AnimatedOpacity visible={false} />                                                                                                                                                             
    ).toJSON()                                                                                                                                                                                        
  ).toMatchSnapshot();                                                                                                                                                                                
});                                                                                                                                                                                                   

it('makes transition', () => {                                                                                                                                                                        
  const component = shallow(<AnimatedOpacityController />);                                                                                                                                           
  expect(renderer.create(component.node).toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();                                                                                                                                 
  component.find('TouchableOpacity').simulate('press');                                                                                                                                               
  expect(renderer.create(component.node).toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();                                                                                                                                 
  component.find('TouchableOpacity').simulate('press');                                                                                                                                               
  expect(renderer.create(component.node).toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();                                                                                                                                 
});
```

Now the generated snapshots will have opacity values as expected.
If you are using animated a lot you can move you mock to `js/config/jest` and edit you package.json to use it in all your tests, then any change made to your stub will be available to all tests.

EDITED:

The solution above solves only to go from beginning to end. A more granular solution is:

1. Don't mock Animated
2. In jest config make `global.requestAnimationFrame = null`
3. Use mockdate do mock the date
4. Use jest.runTimersToTime for time travel

A time travel function would be

```
const timeTravel = (ms, step = 100) => {                                                                                                                                                                              

  const tickTravel = v => {                                                                                                                                                                               
    jest.runTimersToTime(v);                                                                                                                                                                              
    const now = Date.now();                                                                                                                                                                               
    MockDate.set(new Date(now + v));                                                                                                                                                                      
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                       

  let done = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                           
  while (ms - done > step) {                                                                                                                                                                               
    tickTravel(step);                                                                                                                                                                                      
    done += step;                                                                                                                                                                                          
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  tickTravel(ms - done);                                                                                                                                                                                  
};
```

Breaking steps in small chunks is importante because of Animated internal behavior.

Comment: running into the same problem, couldn't get this to work, could you share a sample project?    

can you explain why its necessary to set global.requestAnimationFrame = null and to mock the date?

thanks

Comment: It doesn't work because it can't mock the import when imported from `react-native`: ` Cannot find module 'Animated' from 'BicolorFavoriteCount.test.tsx'`

Answer (score 11):

Aspirina's EDIT was helpful in resolving this issue, but it didn't get the job done directly. For those that follow, this is how I solved the issue of simulating animation progress:

I'm using Jest - this is my setupTests.js script that bootstraps the test environment

```
const MockDate = require('mockdate')
const frameTime = 10

global.requestAnimationFrame = (cb) => {
    // Default implementation of requestAnimationFrame calls setTimeout(cb, 0),
    // which will result in a cascade of timers - this generally pisses off test runners
    // like Jest who watch the number of timers created and assume an infinite recursion situation
    // if the number gets too large.
    //
    // Setting the timeout simulates a frame every 1/100th of a second
    setTimeout(cb, frameTime)
}

global.timeTravel = (time = frameTime) => {
    const tickTravel = () => {
        // The React Animations module looks at the elapsed time for each frame to calculate its
        // new position
        const now = Date.now()
        MockDate.set(new Date(now + frameTime))

        // Run the timers forward
        jest.advanceTimersByTime(frameTime)
    }

    // Step through each of the frames
    const frames = time / frameTime
    let framesEllapsed
    for (framesEllapsed = 0; framesEllapsed < frames; framesEllapsed++) {
        tickTravel()
    }
}
```

The idea here is that we are slowing the requestAnimationFrame rate to be exactly 100 fps, and the timeTravel function allows you to step forward in time increments of one frame. Here's an example of how to use it (imagine I have an animation that takes one second to complete):

```
beforeEach(() => {
    // As part of constructing the Animation, it will grab the
    // current time. Mocking the date right away ensures everyone
    // is starting from the same time
    MockDate.set(0)

    // Need to fake the timers for timeTravel to work
    jest.useFakeTimers()
})

describe('half way through animation', () => {
  it('has a bottom of -175', () => {
    global.timeTravel(500)
    expect(style.bottom._value).toEqual(-175)
  })
})

describe('at end of animation', () => {
  it('has a bottom of 0', () => {
    global.timeTravel(1000)
    expect(style.bottom._value).toEqual(0)
  })
})
```

Long-form write-up with more complete code samples available [here](http://mattmccann.io/time-traveling-to-easily-jest-test-animated-views-in-react-native/)

Comment: Works a treat. Thanks

Comment: This will not work when there are multiple animations in a single js file

Answer (score 5):

You can mock `Animated.View` so that it behaves like a regular view while testing.

```js
jest.mock('react-native', () => {
  const rn = jest.requireActual('react-native')
  const spy = jest.spyOn(rn.Animated, 'View', 'get')
  spy.mockImplementation(() => jest.fn(({children}) => children));
  return rn
});
```

I adapted this from React Transition Group's [example of mocking Transition Groups](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-transition-group/)

Comment: Returning children component makes process easier. Second this answer!

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use Jest to time travel animations for React Native components. Nowadays it is possible to remove the `MockDate` package suggested in other answers, as Jest supports this out-of-the-box by itself. I found this because `MockDate` didn't work with my babel setup.

Here's my modified setup:

```
export const withAnimatedTimeTravelEnabled = () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.useFakeTimers()
    jest.setSystemTime(new Date(0))
  })
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.useRealTimers()
  })
}

const frameTime = 10
export const timeTravel = (time = frameTime) => {
  const tickTravel = () => {
    const now = Date.now()
    jest.setSystemTime(new Date(now + frameTime))
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(frameTime)
  }
  // Step through each of the frames
  const frames = time / frameTime
  for (let i = 0; i < frames; i++) {
    tickTravel()
  }
}
```

To clarify:

- Call `withAnimatedTimeTravelEnabled` in your test script's describe block (or root block) to register Jest timers for the tests.
- Call `timeTravel` in your test script after an animation has been triggered

Comment: working and up to date answer

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am not using `Animated.View` at all. But instead, I have a component that uses `requestAnimationFrame`. The callback actually makes use of the `time` argument so I had to pass the current time to the callback function when replacing `requestAnimationFrame` like so:

```js
global.requestAnimationFrame = (cb) => {
    setTimeout(() => cb(Date.now()), frameTime)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mock Animated.createAnimatedComponent in the following way

```
jest.mock('react-native', () => {
  const rn = jest.requireActual('react-native');
  const spy = jest.spyOn(rn.Animated, 'createAnimatedComponent');
  spy.mockImplementation(() => jest.fn(() => null));
  return rn;
});
```